# JSXGraph: Board without ability to zoom and pan

Tags: zooming, coordinate-systems, jsxgraph

I don't have much experience with JSXGraph and I have a basic question.
How can I create a coordinate system that cannot be zoomed or panned?

I tried:
"var board=JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(divid, { boundingbox:[-5,5,5,-5], axis:true, showNavigation:false, zoom:{wheel:false, pinchHorizontal: false, pinchVertical:false}, pan:{enabled:false}});"

But I can still zoom in this board. What went wrong?

Comment: How do you manage to zoom? Your example in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35tmfqv0/1/)

Comment: I zoom with two fingers on the touchscreen.
You can find a jsfiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/geissbuehlerm/y0cf1bsw/2/#&togetherjs=lhG1d4VDcf
I would like to use an exercise like this for my students and I don't want a point to be moved to the coordinates (10;10) for example or the graph of the function suddenly leave the displayed area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as of version v1.6.2 the API doc and the program logic are not longer in sync. What is missing in the API doc is that by setting the board attribute

```
  zoom: {
    enabled: false
  }
```

zooming should be disabled for all input devices (mouse or multi-touch).
However - by purpose - this does not turn off zooming by pressing zoom buttons. Use the board attribute `showZoom:false` to turn off this possibility.

Further, the API doc is (meanwhile) wrong about `zoom: { wheel: false}` having an effect on pinch-to-zoom. This feature has disappeared some versions ago.
Instead, for v1.6.3+ we just introduced the attribute

```
  zoom: {
    pinch: true
  }
```

which controls if zooming by two fingers is allowed.

**In short:** Add `zoom:{enabled: false}` as board attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and it works fine with zoom:{enabled: false}.